# How to switch back to old YouTube layout?

Tags: youtube

The new YouTube (July 2011) is irritating. Is there a way (or option) I can get the old layout? I tried enabling HTML5 but they changed that layout to look similar to their Flash layout. I hate it. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still switch back and forth between *Cosmic Panda* and the old layout here: http://www.youtube.com/cosmicpanda

I just did it now.

Comment: Its not the old style but i did not find it as annoying as the new. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome:

1. Open a YouTube page
2. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (that is an i as in information)
3. Application tab on top (may have to click the arrows to view more tabs)
4. On the left, in Storage, expand "cookies"
5. Click on the cookie for YouTube
6. On the right, you should see columns for "Name" and "Value"
7. In the Name column, there should be one called "PREF". If this is missing, do something on the YouTube page to create it. Just disable autoplay on a video or change the sort order if you are viewing someone's videos in their profile
8. For PREF, double-click the Value to edit it and replace it with `f6=8` or add it to what is already there with `&f6=8`
9. Click off of the Value or press enter to save it and then refresh the page. All YouTube pages will now use the old layout

---

If you are using Firefox:

1. Open a YouTube page
2. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (that is an i as in information)
3. Click the gear icon on the top right of the window that was opened to view the settings page. Put a check in the box for "Storage"
4. Click on the "Storage" tab
5. Expand "Cookies" on the left and click on the one for YouTube
6. Follow Chrome steps above

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is no way to switch back to old YouTube. Almost all of the users are extremely dissatisfied about the new layout. There are [some discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=5bceb9a722588de2&hl=en)s about the issue on [YouTube's Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/search.py?hl=en&forum=1&query=old%20youtube%20more%3aforum). No working solutions, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch back to an old youtube layout design with help of extension called Switch to youtube extension. However, this works perfectly on Mozilla but for Chrome, it bit dicey especially for the latest version.

I have tried it and here is the result: [Youtube old layout get back test](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/youtube-old-layout.html)